# several actions by single function on jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `form` with several rows, each row contains a check box in a `div` and some other inputs that i include them in a separate `div`.
Within each row if check box is checked, i want other controls to become active, and if unchecked, they should remain disabled.
is there a way to write just one function to do this for all  of my rows?

> i tried to use same `class` name for  `div`, but couldn't figure out the solution.
>   sample structure of my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="TR1" runat="server" Text="trigger1" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-6  col-md-6">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="OP1" runat="server" Text="option1" />
        </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="TR2" runat="server" Text="trigger2" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="OP2" runat="server" Text="option2" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: code in studio please, and if i'm right you can do that without using js

Comment: i need to do that in the client side.

Comment: please show your code, yes i understood that)

Comment: i added sample structure of my rows,

Comment: can you show the 'other controls' which you want to make active?

Comment: checkbox's have pseudo class called `:disabled` and CSS `+` selector to select next element, if you combine them into `input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + next element` you can show or hide optional input fields only with css, but this will not work if you have multiple dependencies like select values, hope that help

Comment: thank you smile0ff, i used this:        $("div input[type=Checkbox]").next().attr('disabled', true) but didn't work

Comment: _"i want other controls to become active, and if unchecked, they should remain disabled."_ Are `input type="checkbox"` elements initially disabled ?

Comment: yes they should be disabled initially,

Comment: @aliziaei _"yes they should be disabled initially"_ How can initially disabled `input type="checkbox"` be checked ?

Comment: the first checkboxes won't be disabled, secondory checkboxes will be disabled.